# AngularJS conflit with limitTo and filter in ngrepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a `ng-repeat` with lot of keywords (> 100 000) that's why I use `limitTo:` but I would like to be able to search in ALL.

```
Search: <input ng-model="filter:queryKeywords" type="text" placeholder="Filter" autofocus>

<label ng-repeat="k in keywords | limitTo:totalDisplayed | orderBy | filter:queryKeywords">
   {{k}}
</label> 

<!-- Will load 100+ keywords -->
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="seeMore()">See More</button>
```

**The problem is** my search only works for items that I can see.

I would like to search in all items (even the one that I can't display).

Thanks!

Comment: It's because the filter in in the template so it would apply to the rendered element only. You need a filter at the data level instead then you can control the limit from there too. angular UI grid would probably work perfectly here though its built in filter are quite good and affect the all data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please could you show me an example, not sure to understand well.

Comment: Given the amount of keywords, perhaps you should also consider doing the search in the backend and returning only the `limitTo` keywords you want, that would send less data through the network and making the frontend to process less data too (of course, I'm assuming you have a backend you can modify, right?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should change the order of the filters, so that searching comes first (and thus applies to all data) and limiting/ordering come afterwards:

```
ng-repeat="k in keywords | 
           filter:queryKeywords |
           limitTo:totalDisplayed |
           orderBy"
```

Comment: @Jose  just out of curiosity how this is different?

Answer (score 4):

Angular applies filters in order. Changing the order of the filters should fix your problem.

```
<label ng-repeat="k in keywords | filter:queryKeywords | limitTo:totalDisplayed | orderBy">
```

This means: First filter, then limit the results to `totalDisplayed` and finally order it.

Comment: @Jose, OnurTOPAL: I just noticed that Onur posted an (almost identical) answer a few minutes before mine. I think his answer should be the accepted one. Onur, there is slight error in your wording: It's `filters` not `directives` (directives are something totally different). Please, correct that to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ExpertSystem Thanks edited. to be honest really don t care about the accepted answer thought there is a problem with mine.